# Could not install ubuntu-private-fonts

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I have signed up for trying out and testing ubuntu beta monospace fonts. When I tried installing that I get the following information and I have not been able to install the font I actually wanted.

Note, selecting 'ttf-ubuntu-font-family' instead of 'ubuntu-private-fonts'
ttf-ubuntu-font-family is already the newest version.

I would like to know why I could not install ubuntu-private-fonts?

Note: I added private repository information in /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 4):

This is just a note, no error or something. There is no "real" package called `ubuntu-private-fonts`. The package in the private repository is called `ttf-ubuntu-font-family`, too. So, if you are an approved member of [this group here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-typeface-interest/), then your package will contain the monospaced font.

If you are an approved member and you added the PPA appropriately then make sure to update your package manager before updating the package itself.

Comment: Thanks, the font is actually there in the list of fonts installed in my machine now.

Comment: Indeed, the `ttf-ubuntu-font-family` package in the beta PPA just has a slightly higher-version number than that in the distribution.  (Note that `ubuntu-private-fonts` hasn't existed for well over six months since it was renamed and the main typeface released!).

Answer (score 0):

I've got this "error " too but after upgrade of 'ttf-ubuntu-font-family' I've found the ubuntu monospace font in my fonts list. I think that it's perfectly normal.

Check your font list :)

Comment: Could you describe what the "error" actually was?  Was it at the command-line, or Software Centre, or a human error (eg. wrong/out-of-date documentation)?